# How to disable button during animation?

Tags: jquery

I'm simply trying to disable a button's ability to be clicked while an animation is firing.

Please note that in the final use, I am using CSS animations fired by jQuery so I can't just check if  **.is(':animated').**

My solution is to change the active class on the button during the animation, but jQuery doesn't seem to be picking up on the fact that I've changed it.

Test Case: http://jsfiddle.net/Ct2TZ/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="button active">Click Me</a>
```

jQuery:

```
var myFunction = function () {
    $('.button').removeClass('active');
    $('.result').append('clicked<br> ');
    $('.result').animate({
        width: '200px'
    }, 2000, function() {        
        $('.result').css({width: '75px'});
        $('.button').addClass('active');
    });
}

// THIS SHOULD NOT WORK DURING ANIMATION
$('.active').on("click", function () {
    myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing as you cant use `:animated` why not just check if the `button` you click has a class of `active` on it?

```
$('.button').on("click", function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    myFunction();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GPRnr/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `on()` and `off()`, that's why they are there, to bind and unbind event handlers :

```
var myFunction = function () {
    $('.button').off('click');
    $('.result').append('clicked<br> ')
                .animate({ width: '200px' }, 2000, function() {        
        $('.result').css({width: '75px'});
        $('.button').on("click", myFunction);
    });
}

$('.button').on("click", myFunction);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct2TZ/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set the event handler for the buttons on document ready (I suppose). This means all the buttons that are active at that moment will have the event handler set.

By saying
`$('.active')`
you are just selecting a bunch of DOM elements,

and by saying
`.on("click", function () {`
you just add a click handler to each of them.

When you later remove the `.active` class, you are not removing the event handler that you set earlier, and thus the click action keeps working.

The solution would indeed be to check for the `.active`class inside the event handler, exactly like @boz did.

Comment: Already accepted boz's answer, but I thank you for the explanation of what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you can't use `:animated`, if you can select a parent somehow, using delegates kinda look like an altogether cleaner solution.

```
$(parent).on('click', '.active', myFunction);
```

Although the other answers here should work as well.