# how to disable button during animation speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, buttonclick

```
 var slideContainer = ('#slider');  
 var width = 720;

 function slide () {  
   if ( parseInt( $slideContainer.css('marginLeft') ) >= -2160 ) {
       $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},200);
   }
 }
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<a class='button' onclick='slide()'></a>
```

i want to disable the button only during the animation duration ( animation speed = 200 milliseconds )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable button during animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111662/how-to-disable-button-during-animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable before animation and use `animate()` complete callback to enable again

```
 function slide () {  
   if ( parseInt( $slideContainer.css('marginLeft') ) >= -2160 ) {
       $('.button').addClass('disabled')
       $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},200, function(){
           $('.button').removeClass('disabled')
       });
   }
 }
```

Comment: ok its great but how can i make a class disabled stop the button .. is it css ?

Comment: Yes do it with css or use an actual `<button>` and do `prop('disabled', true/false)`

Answer (score 1):

My solution includes adding class `disabled` to change css rules for it and also prevent default behavior using JavaScript `preventDefault()` method. Also, an aditional parameter `callback` function will be called at animations end. In that case, the callback function will remove `disabled` class.

```js
var slideContainer = $('#slider');  
var width = 720;

function slide(event) {
  if(!slideContainer.hasClass('disabled')) {
    slideContainer.addClass('disabled');
    slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, 200, function(){
      slideContainer.removeClass('disabled');
    });
  }
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
.disabled {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="slider" class='button' onclick='slide()'>Test</a>
```

Comment: Another solution would be `setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');` and `removeAttribute('disabled');` if the DOM element is a button.

Comment: It's the button that needs to be disabled

Comment: As @k1dev said, only button elements can be disable with native HTML. If you want to keep using <a> tag instead of <button> event.preventDefault() will do the job for you.